# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments

Tags: java, loops, methods

I am facing this problem, I am trying to loop all my methods from one class to another and I did do that, but I have 2 loops where one gets executed from the end to the beginning and then the other one does not get executed. This error shows to me

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments`

This is where I am trying to get the result of my methods

```
public class finalResult {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
        loopUserDataClass();
        loopBankDataClass();
    }

    public static void loopUserDataClass() throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
        userData us = new userData();
        Class<?> getUserDataClass = us.getClass();
        Method[] methods1 = getUserDataClass.getMethods();
        for (Method method : methods1) {
            if (Modifier.isPublic(method.getModifiers())) {
                method.invoke(us, null);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void loopBankDataClass() throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
        bankData bd = new bankData();
        Class<?> getBankClass = bd.getClass();
        Method[] methods = getBankClass.getMethods();
        for (Method method : methods) {
            if (Modifier.isPublic(method.getModifiers())) {
                try {
                    method.invoke(bd, null);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    // Handle the exception here
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

And here is the class where I have my methods.

```
public class bankData {
    public double moneyOnAccount = 123.50;
    public String currencyName = "currencyName";
    public boolean accountState = true;
    public String accountId ="2432432423ffsdf";
    public void getMoneyOnAccount() {
        System.out.println("Money on account: " + this.moneyOnAccount);
    }
    public void getCurrencyName()
    {
        System.out.println("Currency: " + this.currencyName);
    }
    public void getAccountState()
    {
        System.out.println("Account statement: " + this.accountState);
    }
    public void getAccountId()
    {
        System.out.println("Account ID: " + this.accountId);
    }
}
```

I believe that I have a problem with this line

```
 method.invoke(bd, null);
```

I tried to put it in too many different ways but always shows me the same error. I do not have any arguments to pass so I do not know what I have to pass there.

Comment: If you use `System.out.println(" >> " + method.getName());` you can see which methods are causing you issues, like `wait` and `equals`.  I would suggest using `getDeclaredMethods` instead of `getMethods`

Comment: Well, I am starting with Java and it is new think for me. Thank you for brining this up!! I will check the docu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if I modify your code slightly to do...

```
try {
    method.invoke(bd, null);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // Handle the exception here
    //ex.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println(" >> " + method.getName());
}
```

We can get an idea of which methods are causing your issues.  In my testing this prints

```
 >> wait
 >> wait
 >> wait
 >> equals
 >> notify
 >> notifyAll
```

Okay, that actually makes sense, all of those methods will expect one or more parameters.

So, how do we fix it?  Well, instead of using `Method[] methods = getBankClass.getMethods();` you should probably be using `Method[] methods = getBankClass. getDeclaredMethods();`

The difference between the two can be found in the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html)

`Class#getMethods`:

> Returns an array containing `Method` objects reflecting all the public methods of the class or interface represented by this Class object, **including those declared by the class or interface and those inherited from superclasses and superinterfaces.**

`Class#getDeclaredMethods`

> Returns an array containing `Method` objects reflecting all the declared methods of the class or interface represented by this Class object, including public, protected, default (package) access, and private methods, **but excluding inherited methods.**

Comment: That worked! Thank you. But I have one more thing to ask, why worked? It is a little tricky this right there.

Comment: As explained in the JavaDocs, `getMethods` will return ALL the methods of the class, including those inherited from it's super classes (and interfaces), where as `getDeclaredMethods` will return ONLY those methods declared directly by the class